# textarea comment to php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the comment from text area only from html that will appear in php

---

```
  <form action="Untitled-2.php" method="post"></form>
    <b>Comment:</b><br>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment">
     </textarea><br>

    <p>Would you recommend this game to others?</p>
      <input type="radio" name="choice" required>
      <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice">
      <label for="no">No</label><br>

    <p>Can we use your testimonial on our website?</p>
      <input type="radio" name="choice2" required>
      <label for="yes">Yes</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="choice2">
      <label for="no">No</label><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

what should I write in php to get the "Comment" from text area when i push the save button

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried? What doesn't work? How did you access the other fields? fyi, you're missing an opening `<fieldset>` in the form. The PHP documentation has a chapter on [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: it has an open fieldset I forgot to include in the code. sorry  and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a error in your first line
remove  form closing tag from first line.

then in untitled-2.php file write following code

```
<?php

echo $_POST['comment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove  before `<b>Comment:</b><br`> and secondly you must open `<fieldset>`
To retrieve this value, do: `$_POST['comment']`

Answer (score 0):

In you PHP file you can access it via the `$_POST` superglobal, like this `$_POST['comment']`